# Node's Postgres module pg returns wrong date

Tags: node.js, node.js-pg

I have declared a date column in Postgres as date.

When I write the value with node's pg module,  the Postgres Tool pgAdmin displays it correctly.

When I read the value back using pg, Instead of plain date, a date-time string comes with wrong day.

e.g.:

```
Date inserted:              1975-05-11
Date displayed by pgAdmin:  1975-05-11
Date returned by node's pg: 1975-05-10T23:00:00.000Z
```

Can I prevent node's pg to appy time-zone to date-only data? It is intended for day of birth and ihmo time-zone has no relevance here.

Comment: This looks like a bug in node-pg. You're using Brianc's driver ?

Comment: It scares me. I've just proposed a customer to switch from Qt to Node+Web. And the application is full of date/time data

Comment: @DenysSéguret: yes. http://github.com/brianc/node-postgres, "name": "pg", "version": "4.4.0"

Comment: This doesn't look right: https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/blob/master/lib%2FbinaryParsers.js#L132 (and I checked the type for date is 1082)

Comment: It might be a good idea to create a issue in the GitHub project. A solution might be to register a more relevant parser for the date type.

Comment: OK, I did it: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/818

Comment: I have here Postgres 9.4, table with column of type `date`, using `pg` v.4.4, and I'm not seeing the issue described. Is the problem specific to time going over 23:00?

Comment: On which time-zone are you? If the offset is 0 (GMT) you won't notice the problem, I guess.

Comment: I did this, works great: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/429; the code are `pg.types.setTypeParser(1114, function(stringValue) {
    console.log(stringValue);
    return new Date(Date.parse(stringValue + "+0000"));
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT Issue response from Developer on github**

The node-postgres team decided long ago to convert dates and datetimes
without timezones to local time when pulling them out. This is consistent
with some documentation we've dug up in the past. If you root around
through old issues here you'll find the discussions.

The good news is its trivially easy to over-ride this behavior and return
dates however you see fit.

There's documentation on how to do this here:
https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types

There's probably even a module somewhere that will convert dates from
postgres into whatever timezone you want (utc I'm guessing). And if
there's not...that's a good opportunity to write one & share with everyone!

**Original message**
Looks like this is an issue in pg-module.
I'm a beginner in JS and node, so this is only my interpretation.

When dates (without time-part) are parsed, local time is assumed.
pg\node_modules\pg-types\lib\textParsers.js

```
if(!match) {
    dateMatcher = /^(\d{1,})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})$/;
    match = dateMatcher.test(isoDate);
    if(!match) {
      return null;
    } else {
      //it is a date in YYYY-MM-DD format
      //add time portion to force js to parse as local time
      return new Date(isoDate + ' 00:00:00');
```

But when the JS date object is converted back to a string `getTimezoneOffset` is applied.
pg\lib\utils.js s. `function dateToString(date)`

Comment: this answer is awesome. totally made doing what i needed to do easier!

Comment: @Valentin, would you care to share how exactly it is "trivially easy" to get node-pg to return objects without taking TZ into account? A code sample would be great

Answer (score 3):

Just override node-postgres parser for the type date (`pg.types.builtins.DATE` or `1082`) and return the value without parsing it:

```js
import pg from pg

pg.types.setTypeParser(pg.types.builtins.DATE, value => value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is change the data type of the column:

You can do this by running the command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name_1 [SET DATA] TYPE new_data_type,
ALTER COLUMN column_name_2 [SET DATA] TYPE new_data_type,
...;
```

as descripted [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-change-column-type/).

I'd the same issue, I changed to `text`.